# What is this daisy with narrow white petals and a yellow center, that the local deer won't eat?

Tags: identification, perennials, wildflowers

This daisy popped up wild. It has narrow white petals and a yellow center. The local deer don't like it.

It's located in the central California coast. The ground is dry, rocky and semi-shaded.

What daisy is it?

[image: wild daisy]

Comment: @stormy's right! We have a lot of them among our other perennials, like daylillies. They increase each year, and are really pretty. I don't have deer in my neighborhood, so I can't attest to that, but they're definitely easy to grow and I don't have trouble with insects eating them like they do with some of my other plants.

Answer (score 5):

This is a Shasta Daisy. Deer resistant.  No plant is truly is deer proof.  [shasta daisy](http://successfulgardens.com/2010/05/20/perennial-of-the-week-shasta-daisy/)

Comment: Oleander seems to be deer proof in TX.

Answer (score 0):

That's what it looks like to me. It looks just like a Shasta daisy I once had.

Comment: Please don't add answers that simply repeat previous answers. If you agree with a previous ID, you can vote the answer up.

Comment: I am new here and have not completely learned the system yet.

Comment: I understand! Thanks for contributing. We try not to be a forum or discussion group as much as a strict Q and A site. Glad to have you around!